# Printing PRINT6ADDR with DEBUG_ANNOTATE

Tags: c, debugging, contiki

I'm working with Contiki, with the rpl-collect example. I'm trying to print out the debug message, printing the initiation of rpl and the formation of the DAG.

I enabled debug printing with changing the macro `DEBUG_NONE` to `DEBUG_PRINT`, however, it refused to compile as it would print too much and the sky mote doesn't have enough memory.

I changed the macro to `DEBUG_ANNOTATE`, which enabled some of the prints although I don't understand how it works. I did find out that using `printf` instead of `PRINTF` will enable the print out as well, so I managed with that.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to print any pf the `PRINT6ADDR` statements, is there a way to do it?

As the printout are too much I was wondering if it's possible to write in a file through the coffee file system in Contiki?

I would also appreciate if someone could shed some light on the argument of the macro `DEBUG_ANNOTATE` in this code and the best way to manipulate it:

```
#if (DEBUG) & DEBUG_ANNOTATE
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#define ANNOTATE(FORMAT,args...) printf_P(PSTR(FORMAT),##args)
#else
#define ANNOTATE(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
#else
#define ANNOTATE(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Sky mote cannot handle huge log due to limited memory. You can enable the LOG in your desired file (for example, "tcpip.c"). To print IPv6 addresses I use `LOG_INFO_6ADDR()` and `#define LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_INFO` in my desired file.